# Activate UIPanGestureRecognizer After A UILongTapGestureRecgonizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UILongGestureRecognizer on a UIView object.

When the user holds their finger for 1 second, I draw another UIView (a colored box) at the position of where they held their finger.

This newly drawn UIView has a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to it.

However, in order to get the UIPanGestureRecognizer to begin the screen needs to be re-tapped. It seems if my finger is already pressed it doesn't begin receiving inputs until I press on it again.

I want the user to hold their finger, create the box, and then drag that box around (instead of having to tap on the box again and then begin dragging it around).

Do you know how I can pre-activate a UIPanGestureRecognizer to begin from a finger press on top if it at the time of that UIViews creation?

Here is my code for the drag view

```
public func performDrag(recoginizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if(!_drag)
        {
            return
        }
        let point = recoginizer.translationInView(_dragView!)
        switch(recoginizer.state)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                _initialPositionBeforeDragStarted = CGPoint(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y)
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                _initialPositionBeforeDragStarted = nil
                if(_didMoveFinishedCallback != nil)
                {
                    _didMoveFinishedCallback()
                    return
                }
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                frame.origin.x = _initialPositionBeforeDragStarted.x + point.x
                if (frame.origin.x + frame.width > _dragView!.frame.width)
                {
                    frame.origin.x = _dragView!.frame.width - frame.width
                }
                if(frame.origin.x < 0)
                {
                    frame.origin.x = 0
                }
                frame.origin.y = _initialPositionBeforeDragStarted.y + point.y
                if (frame.origin.y + frame.height > _dragView!.frame.height)
                {
                    frame.origin.y = _dragView!.frame.height - frame.height
                }
                if(frame.origin.y < 0)
                {
                    frame.origin.y = 0
                }
            default:
                println("Error: Default hit in perform drag")
        }

        if(_didMoveCallback != nil)
        {
            var globalPoint = window!.convertPoint(frame.origin, fromView: self.superview)
            _didMoveCallback(globalPoint)
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably, you can't. i think UILongPressGestureRecognizer should handle dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in the comment the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` should handle the dragging. After this gesture is recognized it actually works exactly as the pan gesture recognizer.

So if for instance your super view handles the long press method all you need to do is create the subview on state began (as you already seem to do) and in the same method call the child view `performDrag` method with the same gesture. After that even if the user lifts up the finger and pans again the child view will collect data from the new pan gesture recognizer received from itself. Should be simple enough.